# ¿Cómo poner en un Datetime una variable en el atributo min y max?

Tags: javascript, html5, datetime

Tengo la siguiente función en JavaScript donde creo una tabla con inputs adentro, a partir de parámetros recibidos, hay un input type="datetime-local" en donde le pongo los atributos min y max, ¿hay manera de en vez de poner la fecha 'tatuada' (min="2018-01-02") mejor pasarle una variable con una fecha? que quedara de ésta manera (min=VariableConFecha)

```
 function AgregaPregunta(opcion, pregunta, opciones, respuesta, prioridad) {
                var renglon = $("<tr></tr>");
                switch (opcion) {
                    case opcion = 1:
                        renglon.append('<td style="width:10%; vertical-align: middle;"><div class="divNumero"><label></label></div><img style="width: 25px;" src="images/Data-Erase.png" class="imgMinus" title= "Eliminar" /></td>'
                            + '<td colspan="2" style="text-align: justify; width: 60%;"><textarea cols="20" rows="2" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; height: 60px; resize: none; font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">' + pregunta + '</textarea></td>'
                            + '<td style="width:10%;"><label style="font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">Sí/No</label></td>'
                            + '<td style="width:20%;"><label style="font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">' + opciones + '</label></td>'
                            + '<td><label style="font: 12px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;">' + respuesta + '</label></td>'
                            + '<td><input class="valor" type ="number" min="1" style="width: 40px;" /></td>'
                            + '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkN" /></td>'
                            + '<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkN" /></td>'//Nueva Opción 
                            + '<td><select name="cars"> <option value="user">@gmail.com</option> <option value="user">@secuencia.com</option></select ></td>' //Usuarios
                            + '<td><input type="datetime-local" id="dates" min="2018-01-02" max="2018-02-28" value="2018-02-09T00:00"></td>');//Date
                        var td = $('<td style="width:20%;"></td>');
                        td.append(prioridad);
                        renglon.append(td);
                        $("#visualizacionPreg").append(renglon);
                        break;
}
```

Esa es la tabla que se crea a partir de la función de JS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y por que no simplemente guardas esa fecha en una variable y la concatenas tal como lo haces con las variables `opciones`  y `pregunta` ?

Comment: `'<td><input type="datetime-local" id="dates" min="'+VariableConFechaMin+'" max="'+VariableConFechaMax+'" value="2018-02-09T00:00"></td>');//Date`

Comment: @CamiloVasquez no sabía que se podía hacer eso, pero ya lo logré, gracias por la ayuda ;)

Comment: @Naimad muchas gracias, con tu ejemplo, pude hacerlo perfectamente, muchas gracias, si quieres ponerlo cómo respuesta, para marcarla